# IOS sort key value by datetime

Tags: ios

I am new in IOS development. I want to sort NSMutable dictionary by NSDate but could not succeeded. Below are my code:

```
- (void)handleSelectedAssets:(NSMutableDictionary *)selectedAssets {

    NSMutableArray *UUIDs = [NSMutableArray array];
    assetCount = 0;
    NSMutableDictionary *yourMutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in selectedAssets) {
        NSURL *assetURL = [selectedAssets objectForKey:key];

        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:assetURL
                       resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                           NSString *UUID = [self getUUID];
                           UploadAsset *ua = [[[UploadAsset alloc] initWithAssetURL:assetURL] autorelease];

                           ua.delegate = self;
                           ua.UUID = UUID;
                           ua.uploadURL = self.uploadURL;
                           ua.chunkSize = chunkSize;
                           ua.qualityPercent = qualityPercent;

                           [self.uploads addObject:ua];

                           //[self.uploadAssets setObject:assetURL forKey:UUID];

                           [UUIDs addObject:UUID];

                           NSDate *myDate = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];

                           [yourMutableDictionary setObject:UUID forKey:myDate]; // want to sort this dictionary by key.


                           assetCount++;
                           if ([selectedAssets count] == assetCount) {
// After sorting, I want to assign all value to below sendSelectedUUIDs.

                              // NSLog(@"Sort %@",sValues);
                               [self sendSelectedUUIDs:UUIDs];
                               //[self startUploaderQueue];
                               [self handleUploads:ALAssetTypePhoto];
                               [self handleUploads:ALAssetTypeVideo];
                           }
                       } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                           NSLog(@"ALAssetsLibrary Error");
                       }];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one....

```
-(NSMutableArray *)sortByDate:(NSMutableArray *)array objectforKey:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)asc{

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:key ascending:asc];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    return [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:sortedArray];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this:

```
[[yourMutableDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]

    for (NSDate * key in sorted_keys)
    {
      NSMutableString * yourvalue = [yourMutableDictionary valueForKey: key];
      // ....... //
    }
```